# powershell .\trialping.ps1 vs &".\trialping.ps1"

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting-language

I have trialping.ps1 with  below code

```
param([string]$ip)start-job  -ArgumentList $ip -scriptblock {param([string]$ip)& C:\users\pubic\desktop\PingMachine.ps1 -ip $IP}
```

Above code creates a job which runs pingmachine.ps1 which basically pings a machine every 10 sec or so and writes to output.txt in some folder.

If 
1)& ".\trialping.ps1" -ip x.x.x.x is used everything works fine

2)powershell .\trialping.ps1 -ip "x.x.x.x" is used output file is not created.

Why the difference. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case:

1. You start script `.\trialping.ps1`.
2. That script run `Start-Job` cmdlet.
3. `Start-Job` cmdlet create job object and return it.
4. Script ends.
5. Any active job continue to run in background.

In second case:

1. You start new copy of PowerShell.
2. That PowerShell copy run script `.\trialping.ps1`.
3. That script run `Start-Job` cmdlet.
4. `Start-Job` cmdlet create job object and return it.
5. Script ends.
6. PowerShell have nothing more to do and `-NoExit` not provided, so PowerShell close itself and cancel any active jobs in process.

Comment: How can i make it work for the second option. Adding -noexit did not work

Comment: @vindhya What do you want to achieve?

Comment: need to run the script remotely and using  & is giving serialization exception. so looking for alternatives

Comment: How did you run script remotely? When and where did you get that exception? What did error message says? How did you find out that error was caused by `&` operator, but not something your script do or return? Add all that information in your question.

Comment: Using a framework and need to dig very deep to say how remoting is done. But came to know & is causing error bcs if i remove and use powershell everything works fine .

Comment: @vindhya One possible reason of such behavior is that: when you run console application (for example `powershell.exe`) in PowerShell the result will be of type `String`. `String`s can be easily serialized, so no problem here. When you run script directly `.\trialping.ps1 -ip x.x.x.x` (you actually does not need `&` operator here) it can return object of any particular type. Not every type allows serialization, so you can encounter exception here. You can try to workaround this by adding `Out-String`, to convert objects to strings on remote side.